# "insufficient access rights on cross-reference id" error when modifying a license with the LMA

Tags: lma

After clicking Modify License and changing (for example) the expiration date of a license in the License Management App, I get an "insufficient access rights on cross-reference id" error.

This doesn't happen in all cases. The current record I'm having issues with is:

- a recently expired trial license for a Developer Org
- not associated with any lead, account or contact

Not sure that is relevant though, as I am still able to update another license that has the same properties.

Anyone know what could be causing this?